# First element in data getting rerendered rather than updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is something similar to what is happening in my code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJmvXa?editors=1010

Press the Update button to see the issue.

The problem in this codePen, is its only redrawing the first element (Myriel).

I think it must be around the enter,exit or the merge, but I don't fully grasp what's going on.

I thought the merge was to merge existing data with new, and the only data that should go into the enter should be the new data. And the exit is for removing redundant data?

As this graph has both circles and text, should the merge be made on the 'g' element that contains these ?

Perhaps it's to do with the data function :

```
 .data(dataset1.nodes, function(d, i) {
      return d;
    });
```

If i change this to use d.id, it re renders everything again. I presume it's due to the data having an id attribute. How is this suppose to be done ?

```
  // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
  forceNetwork.node = d3
    .select("#nodesContainer")
    .selectAll("g.network-node")
    .data(dataset1.nodes, function(d, i) {
      return d 
    });

  forceNetwork.node.exit().remove();

  forceNetwork.nodeEnter = forceNetwork.node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      return "network-g-node-" + d.id;
    })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
      return "network-node";
    })
    .call(
      d3
        .drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended)
    ).merge(forceNetwork.node);

  forceNetwork.nodeEnter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.id;
    })
    .attr("class", "networkviewer-node")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", 20);

  // Append images
  forceNetwork.nodeEnter
   .append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you'er merging the update and enter selections...

```
forceNetwork.nodeEnter = forceNetwork.node
    .enter()
    .merge(forceNetwork.node);
```

... and, after that, appending the circles (and lines):

```
forceNetwork.nodeEnter
    .append("circle")
```

That will necessarily duplicate the circles and lines.

Instead of that, merge the selection *after* appending the circles and lines to the enter selection, and also change the selection in your `tick` function.

Here is the refactored code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXYozm?editors=1010

Comment: Been banging my head for a while now, thanks a lot. It was setting the forceNetwork.node to be the merge that got me. One more question, the data setting when I return d.id, this uses the DOM id right ? And not the data ? What if I had a unique data element for each piece of data, could I use that here ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy no, it uses the datum's `id`, unless you use `this.id`. Have a look here, in the "Ford Jarrah Kown..." example: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data